# count the consecutive fails in a row together with its start and end date

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, sequence, counting

I have a data.frame with dates and fails. And now I would like to count the consecutive fails of each period together with the date of the start and end date.

For instance,

```
data <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), by = "days",length.out = 14), 
                     fail = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0))

         date fail
1  2019-01-01    1
2  2019-01-02    1
3  2019-01-03    0
4  2019-01-04    0
5  2019-01-05    0
6  2019-01-06    1
7  2019-01-07    1
8  2019-01-08    1
9  2019-01-09    1
10 2019-01-10    0
11 2019-01-11    1
12 2019-01-12    0
13 2019-01-13    0
```

and the result should be

```
  duration      start        end
        2 2019-01-01 2019-01-02
        4 2019-01-06 2019-01-09
        1 2019-01-11 2019-01-11
```

I tried to get the desired results using the difference of index of fails. However, I'm struggling to get the result. About any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
data %>%
 group_by(rleid = with(rle(fail), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 filter(fail == 1) %>%
 summarise(n = n(),
           start = min(date),
           end = max(date)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rleid)

      n start      end       
  <int> <date>     <date>    
1     2 2019-01-01 2019-01-02
2     4 2019-01-06 2019-01-09
3     1 2019-01-11 2019-01-11
```